# Making a div slowly slide down not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

basically here I am trying to make a div slowly slide down upon clicking a link. By, default, the div (see below) is hidden by setting display property to none. Upon the click the div becomes visible (display->block) and slowly slides down. With the following js code, the div simply shows up, without any slidedown movement. You may consider this as trivial but your feedback will very helpful to me. Thank you.

```
<div class="js-app-container" id="subscription_popup" style="padding-top: 70px; display: none;">
// contents inside the divs
</div>

<li class="menu-16246 last">
   <a href="#" class="subscribe-link open_popup" onclick="displaySubscription();">Subscribe</a>
</li>


<script>
    function displaySubscription() {
        // $('.js-app-container').css('display', 'block').fadeIn("slow", function () {});
        var node = document.getElementById('subscription_popup');
        if (node.style.display == 'block') {
            // node.style.display = 'none';
            $('.js-app-container').css('display', 'none').fadeOut("slow", function() {});
        } else
        // node.style.display = 'block'
            $('.js-app-container').css('display', 'block').slideDown("slow", function() {});

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you setup a fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: May be you can create animation from opacity:0 to opacity:1, while sliding down will help.

Comment: Anay, display:block/none doesn't work with animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set css `display` before the animation. If you are not looking for different animations for the `hide` and `show`, you can use `slideToggle` or `fadeToggle`.

```js
function displaySubscription() {
  var node = $('#subscription_popup');
  if (node.is(':visible'))
    $('.js-app-container').fadeOut("slow", function() {});
  else
    $('.js-app-container').slideDown("slow", function() {});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-app-container" id="subscription_popup" style="padding-top: 70px; display: none;">
  // contents inside the divs
</div>

<li class="menu-16246 last">
  <a href="#" class="subscribe-link open_popup" onclick="displaySubscription();">Subscribe</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the css display property before the animations have a chance to run. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function displaySubscription() {
        // $('.js-app-container').css('display', 'block').fadeIn("slow", function () {});
        var node = $('#subscription_popup');
        if (node.is(':visible')) {
            // node.style.display = 'none';
            $('.js-app-container').fadeOut("slow", function() {});
        } else
        // node.style.display = 'block'
            $('.js-app-container').slideDown("slow", function() {});

    }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the `css('display','block')` and `css('display','none')` from all the functions, you don't need them